# Pass console command option through to Symfony CommandTester in PHPUnit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, php-7

I have a Symfony console command configured as below:

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this
       ->setName('crmpiccobundle:list:sync')
       ->setDescription('Sync users to the list')
       ->addOption(
       'filepath',
       null,
       InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
       'The path to the file',
       null
    )
    ;
}
```

...and I have a PHPUnit test for it which looks like this:

```
public function testExecuteWhenFileIsEmpty()
{
    self::bootKernel();

    $application = new Application(self::$kernel);

    $application->add(new Sync());

    $command = $application->find('crmpiccobundle:list:sync');

    $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
    $commandTester->execute([
        'command' => $command->getName(),
        'filepath' => '/tmp/crmpicco.co.uk.csv'
    ]);
}
```

When I run it I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException: The "filepath" argument does not exist.

My question is - how do I pass through an *Option* to the `CommandTester`? Passing arguments is fine, but I can't find docs on how to do it for Options.

Comment: Have you tried with `'--filepath' => '/tmp/crmpicco.co.uk.csv'` ?

Comment: @Matteo Thanks, that is the answer. Please feel free to submit it and I will gladly accept. Cheers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should pass the options with `--` so try this:

```
$commandTester->execute([
    'command' => $command->getName(),
    '--filepath' => '/tmp/crmpicco.co.uk.csv'
]);
```

instead of this:

```
$commandTester->execute([
    'command' => $command->getName(),
    'filepath' => '/tmp/crmpicco.co.uk.csv'
]);
```

Hope this help